# How do I get speech recognition to wait for the next thing I say before continuing in C#

Tags: c#

I just need the speech to pause from reading the if statments until I have said another word. Please see example

Example

```
if (contents.Contains(saved) | contentss.Contains(saved))
{ 
    KEVIN.SpeakAsync("Good job"); 
}
else
{
    KEVIN.SpeakAsync("I do not know what" + saved + "is, Please tell me");

//RIGHT HERE I WANT HER TO PAUSE AND WAIT FOR THE NEXT THING I SAY INSTEAD OF RUSHING THROUGH EVERYTHING

    if(speech.ToLower().Contains(yikes))
    {
        KEVIN.SpeakAsync("Thanks");
        using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\" + userName + "\\Documents\\myvs\\"+ yikes +".txt", true))
        {
            file.WriteLine(likes + ",");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        KEVIN.SpeakAsync("I'm not sure I understand what that even means!");
    }
}
```

Also, Ontop of that question, I know how to read a complete file. But how do I make it read a .txt file looking for a specific word.

```
string contents = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\" + userName + "\\Documents\\Lucy Custom Users\\stuff.txt");
```

In that it is reading that whole file, I want it to still do that but search and try to match an exact word. If thats even possible

Comment: Don't use `KEVIN.SpeakAsync`, just use `KEVIN.Speak`.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure. Give it a shot.

Comment: also fix that formatting of the code you posted.. it's really hard on the eyes at first glance..

Comment: You need a regular expression (http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) for the second part or a simple Contains() call.

Comment: using a justa contains is not working

Comment: string contents = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\" + userName + "\\Documents\\Lucy Custom Users\\stuff.txt");


                    if (speech.ToLower().Contains(contents))
                    {
                        JARVIS.Speak("Cool");

                    }

                    else
                    {
                        JARVIS.Speak("Not cool");
                    }

Comment: How do you get speech input from the user?

Answer (score 0):

You need something other than an asynchronous call at the portion you indicated in your code. Using an asynchronous method will continue to execute independently of the calling method, whereas a synchronous method will wait for the called function to execute before returning to and continuing the calling function.

For example:

```
private void MyAsyncFunction()
{
  DoWork();
  DoWorkAsync();
  DoWork2();
}
```

In this example, DoWork would execute completely and then DoWorkAsync() and DoWork2() would execute at about the same time.

In this example:

```
private void MyAsyncFunction()
{
  DoWork();
  DoWork2();
  DoWork3();
}
```

Everything executes sequentially and waits for the previous function to execute before continuing the next

Comment: I'm sorry, This is confusing. What I mean is I want to say something like "I like birds" It would then say "what kind of birds" and wait for my response... If my response was "blue" it would say you like blue birds. If it was "red" It would say you like red birds.

Comment: Okay, do you know the difference between a synchronous function and an asynchronous function?

Comment: the only difference I know is that Async waits for me to finish. But my delema is I need it to base its next response on my previous response

Comment: Actually Async does *not* wait for you to finish

Comment: No problem, I'll take another look and see if I can help out more clearly